# Can't get cp command to work via CGI-script

Tags: bash

I'm running a web server on a Pi3B+, using Apache. This is for an in-house library project, and the machine runs on its own AdHoc network. It will never have network contact with the outside world, so I'm not worried about security. Through a cgi script, I need to trigger a cp command, but that command is getting ignored. Here's  a very simple bash script that isn't working:

```
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo '<html>'
echo '<head><title>Blah blah blah</title></head>'
echo 'Script is running'
echo '<body>'
/bin/cp /home/pi/query.sh /home/pi/newfile.sh
echo '</body></html>’
```

Similarly, I can't mount an attached drive, echo text to a file, or do anything else that manipulates files or volumes. I understand opening things up this way is a big security hole, but again, security is not an issue in this case. What can I do to allow this kind of access?

EDIT: The script is executing – it's properly echoing text back to the client browser.

Thanks!

Comment: Not enough information.  Have you enabled CGI scripts?  Have you enabled the language for CGI (bash is an unusual choice)?  Have you marked the script executable?

Comment: Oops. Left that part out. Original code snippet is now edited to show that CGI scripts are enabled.

Comment: Programming CGI scripts really does not belong to Raspberry Pi! Please ask at https://stackoverflow.com

Comment: The web server runs with userid=www-data, group=www-data, have you changed permissions to allow that userid or group to write to /home/pi (owned by userid=pi and group=pi)?

Answer (score 0):

I copied and executed your code on a Pi3B+ and got an error. The last single-quote on

```
echo'<body></html>'
```

is the wrong type (looks like a start-single-qoute). This could just be a copy and paste error and not the issue. However, once I fixed that, the cp command worked as expected.

Comment: This does not answer a question to Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Thanks, tbitson. Alas, it was just a copy/paste problem. The single-quote is fine on mine. As near as I can tell, this is a permissions problem, so it's interesting that it's working for you. On my machine, Apache is still owned by www-data. Have you changed your permissions for that account?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that the CGI script does not have write access to `/home/pi`.

You should check the webserver's error log for error messages.  If this is debian based and apache based, probably `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.
Alternatively, change the copy line to:

```
/bin/cp /home/pi/query.sh /home/pi/newfile.sh 2>&1
```

so that it's errors are displayed.

One option to fix this is to chmod the directory to allow world write access.
This is a bad choice for the user's home directory.
Better would be to make another directory (possibly a subdirectory of /home/pi) to hold the files in question, and make that world writable.